# How to make `link_to` work correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one page with a button to create a new album of photos on my app like this:

```
<span class="file-upload">
  <%= link_to '', new_album_path, class: "btn-upload trigger-file-upload"%>
</span>
```

My routes.rb is like this:

```
resources :albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

If I click directly on my page like this, it works:

```
https://localhost:3000/albums/new
```

Why the link generated by <%= link_to '', new_album_path, class: "btn-upload trigger-file-upload"%> doesnt works? I click on it, and the page isnt redirected

Edited: My rake routes:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `click on the "link_to"`. I suppose you do not mean that there is a link on the rendered page that says "link_to".

Comment: can you show output of rake `routes | grep albums` by running it on console on project directory?

Comment: where does page redirects on click on this link? do you get any error?

Comment: Nothing happens. I inspect the code, and its like this: <a class="btn-upload trigger-file-upload" href="/albums/new"></a>. 

If I click it on directly on the inspector, it works. Maybe some JS issue?

Comment: Your question didn't understand please ask clearly

Answer (score 1):

More of a "teach how to fish" but to determine what routes are available in your application and the cooresponding paths you should run

`rails routes | grep album`

That will show you all of the possible named routes along with their path and associated controller.  Yours is most likely named `new_album_photo_path` for getting a link to upload a new image.  Always consult the rails routes though when you have a question.

Comment: OP wants to create an album resource first before adding a photo.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use new_album_path, you need to have resources :photos in your routes.rb file. So you need to only keep:

```
resources :photos
```

instead of

```
resources :albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is good except one thing text for anchor, so when you click on that text and it will open `https://localhost:3000/albums/new`.

`<span class="file-upload">
    <%= link_to 'Create New Album', 
 new_album_path, class: "btn-upload trigger-file-upload" %>
</span>`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you tell me what link it shows when you hover on it?? And please share CSS code of 'file-upload' class. I think the problem is with its CSS.

Comment: /albums/new . But when I click nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem on my javascript, that makes the click button being overrided

```
 $('.trigger-file-upload').click(function(event){
    form = $(this).parents('.file-upload').parent();
    field = $(this).parents('.file-upload').find('input[type="file"]');
    field.trigger('click');

    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
 <span class="file-upload">
<a class="btn-upload trigger-file-upload" herf=" <%=  new_album_path%>"</a>
 </span>
```